# BASH: how to pass a default argument if no arguments after the first were passed

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I have a bash script with a `case` statement in it:

```
case "$1" in 
    bash)
        docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) /bin/bash
        ;;
    shell)
        docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py shell
        ;;
    test)
        docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test "${@:2}"
        ;;
esac
```

On the `test` command, I want to pass the default argument of `apps`, but only if the user didn't pass any arguments other than `test` to the bash script.

So, if the user runs the script like this:

```
./do test
```

it should run the command

```
docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test apps
```

However, if they run the script like this:

```
./do test billing accounts
```

it should run the command

```
docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test billing accounts
```

How can I test for the existence of arguments *after* the first argument?

Comment: `[[ $# -ne 1 ]]`... or, more correctly, `(( $# != 1 ))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd try to use bash variable substitution:

```
   test)
        shift
        docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test "${@-apps}"
        ;;
```

Other way is to check `$*` instead of `$1`:

```
case $* in 
    bash)
         ...
    test)
         docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test apps
         ;;
    test\ *)
         docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py test "${@:2}"
         ;;
```

Comment: Did that edit mess it up?  Should there be a `:` in `"${@:-apps}"`?

Comment: @synic - the : will default even for a null valued second argument, and so doesnt answer the question asked. Without the : it will default only if there is no second argument.

Comment: The test of $@ doesnt test for two arguments *(and the white space would need escaping in the pattern anyway)*.

Comment: @mikeserv Do you mean to change to `$*`?

Comment: Not exactly. See the comments on BinaryZebra's answer. It still doesnt test for two arguments. It looks for a concatenation of argument(s) that starts with the pattern `test\ `. And so if the first argument starts w/ `test\ ` it means nothing. Both of you guys should be using `?` anyway. But it isnt a robist test regardless.

Comment: Try like: `${#1}:$*` and a pattern like `4:test?*` - basically you cannot affirm a second argument based only on a test of either of $* or $@. Its not enough information.

Answer (score 2):

something like this would work well

```
if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
fi
```

Comment: I'd rather say `[ "$#" -ne "2" ]` , as you could very well pass an empty 2nd argument :    `myscript  foo "" bar baz` # has 4 args, and the arg $2 is empty

Comment: @OliverDulac - i dont think `[ 2 -ne "$#" ]` is a very useful test here. It negates every number of args but 2.

Comment: @mikeserv: the poster tests only the 2nd arg, and say "no argument" (without s). If there can be more than 2, then `if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then echo "Not enough arguments supplied: you need at least 2"; fi` will be fine. The point of my comment being still the same: testing for the 2nd argument's length doesn't tell you how many arguments were supplied...

Comment: @OliverDulac - true. The absence of a second argument does, though. `[ "${2+:}" ]` is probably the most simple way to robustly test for 2 or more arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
case $1:$# in
(test:1)
    docker $(this is bad) python test apps;;
(test:$#)
    docker $(still bad) python "$@";;
(bash:$#)
    docker ...
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just reset your args however you want using `set ...`

```
case "$1" in 
    #...
    test)
        [ $# -lt 2 ] && set test apps
        docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) python manage.py $@
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

If arguments do not have spaces or newlines.
Transform the arguments into an string: `"$*"`, and use that:

```
f(){ docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q web) "$@"; }

case "$*" in
    bash)       f /bin/bash                    ;;
    shell)      f python manage.py shell       ;;
    test)       f python manage.py test apps   ;;
    test\ ?*)   f python manage.py "$@"        ;;
esac
```

Using a function to manage code (not a variable) and remove repetition.